# How do I obtain the current font size and baseline skip of a beamer font?

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I'm creating a document using the document class `beamer` for the first time. The `\title` is a little bit too large and I would like to decrease the font size slightly. I've figured out that I can change the font using `\setbeamerfont{title}{size*={<font size>}{<baseline skip>}}`. However, rather than setting the font size and baseline skip to fixed values, I would like to change them relatively to their current values. So, is there a way to figure out what their current values are?

Answer (score 1):

Try `\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\relsize{-1}}`, with `relsize` package loaded. This avoids knowing the exact value.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't work as I would expect. It even changes the font size when I use `\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\relsize{-0}}`.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Can you provide a complete example showing the problem?